# Regex - Check a bracket/parenthese is not closed (including nested)

Tags: php, regex, notepad++

I would like to have a match when a bracket/parenthese is not closed, or if one is closed but not opened, including nested (using notepad++ regex search).

For example :

`[Text]` (ok)

`[Text` (not ok)

`Text]` (not ok)

`[Text (test]` (not ok)

`[Text test)]` (not ok)

`[Text (test)]` (ok)

It could be nice if I can do the same with the { and }.

Can ou help me please ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's certainly better to parse the string, nevertheless, here is a way to do the job with Notepad++

You have to match four possible strings:

1 Open bracket without close:

```
^.*?\[(?!.*?\])[^\]]*$

  ^         : begining of string
    .*?     : 0 or more any char, not greedy
    \[      : open bracket
    (?!     : negative lookahead
      .*?   : 0 or more any char, not greedy
      \]    : close braket
    )       : end lookahead
    [^\]]*  : 0 or more any char but close braket
  $         : end of string
```

2 close bracket without open:

```
^[^[\r\n]*\].*?$

  ^         : begining of string
  [^[\r\n]* : O or more any char, except open bracket and linebreak
  \]        : close bracket
  .*?       : 0 or more any char
  $         : end of string
```

3 open parenthesis without close, same explanation than open bracket:

```
^.*?\((?!.*?\))[^)]*$
```

4 close parenthesis without open, same explanation than close bracket:

```
^[^(\r\n]*\).*?$
```

*I let you do the same thing for `{` and `}`.*

Put all them together, joined by `|`:

```
^(?:.*?\[(?!.*?\])[^\]]*|[^[\r\n]*\].*?|.*?\((?!.*?\))[^)]*|[^(\r\n]*\).*?)$
```

Comment: It's just awesome, thanks a lot, it deals with all my cases ! I

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do it by using a regex: the class of languages recognized by DFAs (Languages of type 3 - [Deterministic Finite Automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton)) can be expressed by regexes but you need to simulate a PDA (Languages of type 2 - [Push Down Automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton)) to control matching brackets.

It's formally proved that it's not possible to do it via regex.

A simple solution is to use a counter initialized to `0`: scan the string and increase it every time you find a `(` or decrease it every time you find a `)`.

If the counter goes under zero, the expression is not well formed.

I recommend you to use only a type of brackets, otherwise you need one counter for each type of brackets and some control statements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Oh, bad :/ It's cause of the nested cases ? Is there a solution without taking account of it ?

Comment: The reason comes from the theory of formal language and it's briefly explained in the pages I linked you.
The simplest solution is the one I showed you, use only `(` and `)`. If you want to match more types of brackets you have 2 solutions: you can simulate a stack or, if you are not familiar with it, you can take a counter for each type and make the proper controls.